# Move gantry system to detected position in image plane

Tags: computer-vision, industrial-robot, precise-positioning, transformation

I have the following simplified gantry system (cartesian robot) that can move in the x axis direction:

[image]

My goal is to position the red pointer on top of the target (i.e., I want the real world x-coordinates of the pointer and the target to be the same). I have a vision system above the gantry and I am using two aruco markers. This way I can detect the position of the target and the carriage in the image plane. Hence, I know their x-coordinates in pixels.

Knowing the positions of the target and carriage arucos, how can I compute the position in the image plane (x-coordinate in pixels) where the carriage aruco should be after moving the gantry and positioning the red pointer just on top of the target aruco?

Any advice on how to make the system more accurate/robust?

Answer (score 1):

You could do a manual calibration:

- Measure a far left `x_target` aruco in camera pixels (`x_pixel_left`),
- Put the pointer on that target and measure the corresponding carriage aruco position in camera pixels (`x_carriage_left`),
- Do the same for a far right position (`x_pixel_right` and `x_carriage_right`),

And then at runtime:

- Find the actual `x_target` in the camera image,
- Calculate the ratio of this `x_target` pixel position wrt `x_pixel_left` and `x_pixel_right`,
- Calculate the target carriage pixel position using the same ratio wrt `x_carriage_left` and `x_carriage_right`,
- Move your carriage accordingly.

If this is not accurate enough, you could add extra calibration points between far left and far right.

Alternatively, you could do a full [camera calibration](https://www.google.com/search?q=extrinsic+camera+calibration) but that is more involved, and probably overkill unless your goal is to extend this to multiple degrees of freedom.

Comment: Very useful! However I don't see how a full camera calibration will help here, since I don't have an easy way of computing the world coordinates of the target arucos. I only have the position info of the image plane.